# How to Shell Script to delete multiple files from multiple servers and paths?

Tags: shell, unix

Write a shell script to delete multiple files from multiple folders and servers and each time SSH to a different server. List of server names and file paths should come from a input file. After deleting the files, it should write an output file with all the files deleted along with the paths and server names.

I tried to input the server names and path from a text file and tried to read it.

Comment: Can you show us what code you've tried so far?  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, 
Please read  the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash) and more generally [mcve]..  We can't help you fix your code if you don't include it, along with sample inputs and expected outputs. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Output file paths
deleted_files_log="deleted_files.log"
not_found_files_log="files_not_found.log"
error_log="error.log"

# Ensure log files are empty or create them if they don't exist
> "$deleted_files_log"
> "$not_found_files_log"
> "$error_log"

# Read input file line by line
while IFS=, read -r server path; do
# Check if server and path variables are correctly populated
echo "Server: $server"
echo "Path: $path"

# Attempt SSH connection and execute commands
ssh -T username@"$server" <<EOF
    cd "$path" && \
    rm -f file1 file2 file3 file4 2>error.log && \
    echo 'file1,file2,file3,file4' >> "$deleted_files_log" || \
    echo 'file1,file2,file3,file4' >> "$not_found_files_log"
EOF

# Check the exit status of the SSH command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # SSH connection or command execution failed, log the error
    echo "Error: Could not SSH to $server or execute commands" >> 
"$error_log"
fi

done < servers.csv
```

Comment: Very good. I don't have a way to test it, but https://shellcheck.net shows only 3 lines of concern, so I'm upvoting this. (Some indentation will make you code easier to browse.)

Comment: grep -o 'facilityId=[0-9]\{5\}' filename.txt | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort | uniq -c